# How to use grunt-html installed globally?

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

I would like to use `grunt-html` task to check my HTML files.

I install the task *locally* with `npm install grunt-html` and use it in `grunt.js` as follows:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-html');

    grunt.initConfig({

        htmllint:{
            all:['*.html']
        },

    });

};
```

Now I would like to install the `grunt-html` task *globally*.

Unfortunately after removing the local `grunt-html` node module and installing it *globally* `grunt` fails to load the task. While running `grunt htmllint` I get:

```
>> Local Npm module "grunt-html" not found. Is it installed?
```

If I remove `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-html');` from the `grunt.js` file I get:

```
 Task "htmllint" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

So my question is how to use `grunt-html` installed *globally*?

Answer (score 13):

gruntjs doesn't currently support loading globally-installed grunt modules from `loadNpmTasks`, per the documentation of [`grunt.loadNpmTasks`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.loadnpmtasks):

> This plugin must be installed locally via npm, and must be relative to the grunt.js gruntfile.

Of course, if you really insist on installing it globally, a hack would be to create a symlink (`ln -s`) from your local `node_modules` directory to your global `node_modules/grunt-html` directory.

If you're doing module development, another alternative would be to use the under-appreciated `npm link` command that lets you locally install a module that exists elsewhere on you system (see `npm help link` for usage information).

Both of these approaches, though, don't allow you to truly install the `grunt-html` package globally.