# Make grunt-eslint use globally installed eslint plugin

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-eslint

Calling `grunt-eslint` causes a `Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react'` error that doesn't happen when calling `eslint` directly from the command line.

I have `eslint-plugin-react` installed globally.

Is there an easy way to make `grunt eslint` behave the same way as `eslint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to install the node module locally for some reason, I can think of two options. 1. Use grunt-exec within your grunt file to run eslint, or 2. As per the answer in the link below setup a symbolic link to your global node modules folder:
[How to use grunt-html installed globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130349/how-to-use-grunt-html-installed-globally)